# Tkinter program displays blank screen on linux, works on windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, tkinter

I've been writing this code for a slideshow program in Linux. The problem I'm having is that when run from a windows environment it works perfectly (Full-screen resized images), however when run from a virtual Linux (Ubuntu x64) environment a blank white canvas appears with no images being displayed.

The code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os
import glob
import random

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, delay):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.h = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.delay = delay
        self.pictures = []
        self.track_img_ndex = 0
        for img in image_files:
            self.pictures.append(img)
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def show_slides(self):
        if self.track_img_ndex < len(self.pictures):
            x = self.pictures[self.track_img_ndex]
            self.track_img_ndex +=1
            original_image = Image.open(x)
            resized = original_image.resize((self.w, self.h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            self.picture_display.config(image=new_img)
            self.picture_display.image = new_img
            self.title(os.path.basename(x))
            self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
        else:
            print("End of list!")

delay = 5000
playlist = glob.glob(r'\mnt\hgfs\E\Images\*.*')
random.shuffle(playlist)
image_files = playlist

app = App(image_files, delay)
app.show_slides()
app.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: linux uses `/` path separators.

Comment: @Alexander I’m so embarrassed  thank you.

Answer (score -1):

winfo_screenwidth() and winfo_screenheight() give not correct display size on Linux. Use full-screen mode to fix it.

The code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os
import glob
import random


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, delay):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        # start window size (any)
        self.w = 500
        self.h = 500

        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)  # Activate full-screen mode

        # Change full-screen mode bind
        self.bind("<F11>", lambda event: self.attributes("-fullscreen",
                                                         not self.attributes("-fullscreen")))
        # Bind full-screen mode exit
        self.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: self.attributes("-fullscreen", False))

        self.geometry("%dx%d+100+100" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.delay = delay
        self.pictures = []
        self.track_img_ndex = 0
        for img in image_files:
            self.pictures.append(img)
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def show_slides(self):
        if self.track_img_ndex < len(self.pictures):
            x = self.pictures[self.track_img_ndex]
            self.track_img_ndex += 1
            original_image = Image.open(x)

            window_size_now = (self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())  # Getting current window size :

            resized = original_image.resize(window_size_now, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            self.picture_display.config(image=new_img)
            self.picture_display.image = new_img
            self.title(os.path.basename(x))
            self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
        else:
            print("End of list!")


_delay = 5000
playlist = glob.glob(r'/home/yaroslav_admin/PycharmProjects/LearnPython_01/imgs/*.*')
random.shuffle(playlist)
_image_files = playlist

app = App(_image_files, _delay)

app.after(100, app.show_slides)  # delayed start,
# because tkinter need some time to count full-screen window size in main loop !
app.mainloop()
```